# Open client side program using Javascript

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have created a Java program which takes some command line arguments to run.  I need to make a browser extension to the program so that the program can be opened with data from the browser.

I know Javascript does not allow any local file access, but there are programs which doing the  task I needed.

Examples are Internet Download Manager which has the browser extension for running it receiving command line arguments from the browser.  Obviously extensions for most of the browsers including Chrome and Firefox are made using Javascript?  Is there any way to do local program execution via JavaScript (I think there's a way surely)?

Comment: What browser are we talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly run anything from your JS sandbox on client PC (just think about security risks!) There's other method however: Make your application register itself as protocol handler when it installs and use links with this protocol on your pages (think how e-mail clients serve mailto: or torrent clients serve magnet: links). Since you control both sending and receiving side, you can pass pretty much any information in those. You can find Windows example for registering a handle [at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Should you need it for any other system, I'm pretty sure searching for "system_or_gui_name register protocol handler" will show you desired result among the first.